# How can I block unwanted devices connected to AWS RDS instance?

Tags: android, mysql, amazon-web-services, subnet, vpc

I am developing a project where client-server register the products and save them to the AWS cloud database. The data stored in the cloud is allowed to access mobile apps which are given access to public use.

So basically, the registered user will log in and see the data stored in the cloud.

I had tried accessing the database from different IPs.

What I am expecting is to have a range of IP assigned to RDS cloud or put the country gateway, so only the people from a country can use the app.

How can I overcome this issue?

Thanks for help

Comment: You should turn off the public accessibility and only use the rds as private. That is better. If you connect to rds outside, then you can proxy through ssh with an ec2.

Comment: Your mobile app connects directly to RDS?

Comment: yes. it is@RodrigoM

Answer (score 1):

You should not design your App where the app need to connect directly to the database. The [database should in private subnet](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/connecting-to-a-database-within-an-amazon-vpc/) so can only accessible within VPC or disable the public access of the Database its really risky to make your database public.

[image]

[when-you-accidentally-put-your-database-on-a-public-subnet-in-aws](http://www.smashcompany.com/technology/when-you-accidentally-put-your-database-on-a-public-subnet-in-aws)

Now the question is how the App will communicate, well a simple server should be placed in the middle of App and RDS.

To access RDS put RDS in private subnet and access RDS from Bastion server.

Or if the above as per your question is use case then Allow IP range or proxy through EC2 instance but the first one is recommended.

[image]